# Create libraries that need a common library

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am working in a very large iOS project and it has so many classes and resources that it takes very long time to index and compile them. As it still grows more and more, I need to do something about this because I am spending too much of my time waiting for the IDE to let me work.

My first idea was to pack all the images in a custom bundle so the IDE will see it as a single file and would be faster to index and copy it, but I have seen that a bundle is nothing more than a simple folder with an extension, so I guess that the performance would still be slow. Then I read that if I used "blue folders" instead of "yellow groups" for my images, Xcode would not index them. But this way is not easy right now, as I should replace my function that looks for images to look for them in that folder (absolute paths?)

So my last approach will be saving time in both compile time and indexing. I want to modularize my code in multiple libraries so it will not be necessary to compile it "ever" again and this way Xcode won't need to index the source files neither.

I have followed some tutorials and now I know how to create a static library and include the header files in another project. But my current problem is as follows.

My application has several "independent" modules, so I want to create a static library for each one (and maybe I'll generate an image bundle for each one too...). But all of those modules use a common core, which I'd like to maintain in a static library too. So, if I do it like this, I will have to include the main core library in every module library, and I'm afraid this will not be the most optimum way, as the binary code of the core will be there several times, right?

I guess the correct solution would be to generate a dynamic library for the core and static ones for the modules, but I can't find how to generate the dynamic one... Furthermore, I'm not sure this would be the solution.

So I ask you: what options do I have? Is compiling the core several times the best approach I have?
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic linking is not supported in IOS, so this isn't an option.  While the static libraries are added to the other libraries, it isn't embedded inside the other static library, you can see this when you do a build, the other libraries should show as a separate libraries inside the project folder, hence each static library/project will only get included once in the app build.

In the end ... I am not sure this will save you a lot of time you are expecting if you are using static libraries in the same workspace.  I use static libraries in some projects and if I do a Clean on the app, then a build, the static library will get re-built also.

Comment: Ok, I think I didn't express correctly. What I meant is that I create a library libA. Then I create a library libB that internally uses libA. When compiling libB, it will include libA.
So then I create libC which also uses libA. And libD, libF, ...
My project uses those libB, libC, libD, ... but not libA directly. My problem is that libA is huge (10MB), and so all the others will be too (when actually, they source is very little).